# installing Lenovo System Update: error code 1316: network error acessing System Update.msi

Tags: windows-7, updates

I'm trying to install an update of Lenovo System Update but encountered this error. I tried to remove the old version but I can't find it installed on my system through add/remove programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you deleted files from the folder `C:\Windows\Installer`. Download the old Version of the tool, extract the Setup and store the MSI on your HDD and when you install the new Version, point to the old MSI file.

Comment: While I'm sure this would have worked, I wasn't able to find the same version (3.x) on lenovo's website. Without doing any further searching, I was fortunately able to remove the old system update through CCleaner. It has an uninstall software feature and the old system update showed up there. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Oh, and after removing the old version, I was able to install the new system update version 5.